# How to Stop Animation in Plotly Dash When Callback is Triggered

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have an animation in Dash which is a simulation that requires a number of factors. Right now, if I want change any of the parameters in my simulation, I have to wait for the animation to end, change the parameter, then play the animation again. Otherwise, I get unexpected behaviour like what is shown in the recording below.

[image]

I was wondering if there was a way to make it so that when a parameter is updated, we just forget about the previous simulation immediately and the graph goes back to step 1 with the new parameters. Then the user can press `Play` again see the new simulation. Below is the current code.

```
def callbacks_graph(app):
    # callback for plotting animation

    @callback(
        Output("probability_graph", "figure"),
        Input("bound_input", "value"),
        Input("mass_input", "value"),
        Input("end_time_input", "value"),
        Input("n_particles_input", "value"),
        Input("components_table", "data"),
        blocking=True
    )
    def animate_probabilities(bound, mass, end_time, n_particles, components):
        # components check
        # LOTS OF CALCULATIONS TO FIND PROBABILITY DENSITIES

        # define layout
        layout = {
            # LOTS OF LAYOUT PARAMETERS
        }

        # define frames
        frames = []
        for i in range(len(t)):
            data = [
                # SIMULATION DATA
            ]
            frames.append({
                "data": data,
                "name": str(t[i])
            })
        
        # define slider
        sliders_dict = {
            "active": 0,
            "yanchor": "top",
            "xanchor": "left",
            "currentvalue": {
                "visible": True,
                "xanchor": "right"
            },
            "transition": {"duration": 0.1, "easing": "cubic-in-out"},
            "pad": {"t": 20},
            "len": 0.9,
            "x": 0.05,
            "y": 0,
            "steps": [{
                "args": [
                    [t[i]],
                    {
                        "frame": {"duration": 0.1, "redraw": False},
                        "mode": "immediate",
                        "transition": {"duration": 0.1}
                    }
                ],
                "method": "animate"
            } for i in range(len(t))]
        }
        layout["sliders"] = [sliders_dict]

        # make figure
        fig_dict = {
            "data": data,
            "layout": layout,
            "frames": frames
        }
        return go.Figure(fig_dict)
```